# AngularJS Routing Resolve Service not triggering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, sharepoint-online

Basic knowledge of AngularJS.
I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/811782/AngularJS-Security-Authorization-on-Angular-Routes) for using routing to implement a Role-based app that redirects user to different views, depending on their roles.

**The Issue**

When I load the initial page, despite no errors appearing, it doesn't seem to trigger neither the "authorizationService" nor any of the routes. I have placed breakpoints in both the service and the routes' resolve and none of them are being triggered.

Right now, the default page loads the empty "/" templateView, despite logged in user having group permissions related to the other views, which should show first.

**Code**

My main app.js looks like this:

```
"use strict";

var roles = { 
    compras : "Compras",
    tesoreria: "Tesoreria",
    cuentasPorPagar: "Cuentas Por Pagar",
    masterData: "Master Data"
};

var app = angular.module("proveedorApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {   
        $routeProvider.when("/Compras", {
            templateUrl: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/SiteAssets/Angular/Templates/compras.html",
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            controller: "comprasCtrl",
            resolve: {
                permission: function(authorizationService, $route) {
                    return authorizationService.permissionCheck([roles.compras]);
                },
            }
        }).when("/Tesoreria", {
            templateUrl: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/SiteAssets/Angular/Templates/tesoreria.html",
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            controller: "tesoreriaCtrl",
            resolve: {
                permission: function(authorizationService, $route) {
                    return authorizationService.permissionCheck([roles.tesoreria]);
                },
            }
        }).when("/CuentasPorPagar", {
            templateUrl: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/SiteAssets/Angular/Templates/cuentasPorPagar.html",
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            controller: "cuentasPorPagarCtrl",
            resolve: {
                permission: function(authorizationService, $route) {
                    return authorizationService.permissionCheck([roles.cuentasPorPagar]);
                },
            }
        }).when("/MasterData", {
            templateUrl: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/SiteAssets/Angular/Templates/masterData.html",
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            controller: "masterDataCtrl",
            resolve: {
                permission: function(authorizationService, $route) {
                    return authorizationService.permissionCheck([roles.masterData]);
                },
            }
        }).when("/NoAccess", {
            templateUrl: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/SiteAssets/Angular/Templates/inicio.html",
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            controller: "inicioCtrl"
        }).when("/", {
            templateUrl: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/SiteAssets/Angular/Templates/inicio.html",
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            controller: "inicioCtrl"
        })

    });
```

And the "authorizationService" used is the following:

```
"use strict";

app.factory('authorizationService', function ($resource, $q, $rootScope, $location) {
    return {
        // We would cache the permission for the session,
        //to avoid roundtrip to server
        //for subsequent requests

        permissionModel: {
            permission: {},
            isPermissionLoaded: false
        },

        permissionCheck: function (roleCollection) {

            // we will return a promise .
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            //this is just to keep a pointer to parent scope from within promise scope.
            var parentPointer = this;

            //Checking if permission object(list of roles for logged in user) 
            //is already filled from service
            if (this.permissionModel.isPermissionLoaded) {
                //Check if the current user has required role to access the route
                this.getPermission(this.permissionModel, roleCollection, deferred);
            } else {
                //if permission is not obtained yet, we will get it from  server.
                // 'api/permissionService' is the path of server web service , used for this example.
                var permissionsRestCall = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/currentuser/groups?$select=title';

//                $resource('/api/permissionService').get().$promise.then(function (response) {
                $resource(permissionsRestCall).get().$promise.then(function (response) {
                    //when server service responds then we will fill the permission object
//                    parentPointer.permissionModel.permission = response;
                    var groups = $($(reponse).find('entry content'));
                    var names = $.map(groups, function(x){ return $(x).text() });
                    parentPointer.permissionModel.permission = names;

                    //Indicator is set to true that permission object is filled and 
                    //can be re-used for subsequent route request for the session of the user
                    parentPointer.permissionModel.isPermissionLoaded = true;

                    //Check if the current user has required role to access the route
                    parentPointer.getPermission(parentPointer.permissionModel, roleCollection, deferred);
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        //Method to check if the current user has required role to access the route
        //'permissionModel' has permission information obtained from server for current user
        //'roleCollection' is the list of roles which are authorized to access route
        //'deferred' is the object through which we shall resolve promise
        getPermission: function (permissionModel, roleCollection, deferred) {
            var ifPermissionPassed = false;

            angular.forEach(roleCollection, function (role) {
                switch (role) {
                    case roles.compras:
                        if (permissionModel.includes(roles.compras)) {
                            ifPermissionPassed = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case roles.tesoreria:
                        if (permissionModel.includes(roles.tesoreria)) {
                            ifPermissionPassed = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case roles.cuentasPorPagar:
                        if (permissionModel.includes(roles.cuentasPorPagar)) {
                            ifPermissionPassed = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case roles.masterData:
                        if (permissionModel.includes(roles.masterData)) {
                            ifPermissionPassed = true;
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        ifPermissionPassed = false;
                }
            });
            if (!ifPermissionPassed) {
                //If user does not have required access, 
                //we will route the user to unauthorized access page
                $location.path("/NoAccess");
                //As there could be some delay when location change event happens, 
                //we will keep a watch on $locationChangeSuccess event
                // and would resolve promise when this event occurs.
                $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (next, current) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                });
            } else {
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

My main page is just basically a Div container. For what it matters, this DIV container is inserted in a ScriptEditor WebPart in a SharePoint WebPart Page hosted on SharePoint Online 2013.

```
<div ng-app="proveedorApp"> Aqui se comienza
<div ng-view>
</div>
```

Each templateView, right now only has a `<p> This is view X </p>` element for reference.

*Edited: Missed the ng-view inside the ng-app*

*Edited: Clarified current behavior of default page*

Comment: In general the use of  `$q.defer()` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. It is better to return promises derived from `.then` methods, rather than manufacture new promises with `$q.defer()`. When using `$q.defer` every branch of an [if then else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) needs to either resolve or reject the `$q.defer` or the promise will hang. Your code has lots of branches that do neither.

Comment: @georgeawg I can work on that. However, would that change the fact that the function "authorizationService.permissionCheck" is never called? No breakpoints at that method seem to hit when I load the page